# How to escape delimiter within a field when there also are unmatched quotes on them

Tags: r

I have a large dataset which has both unmatched quotes and delimiters (semicolon) within fields. Here is an example:

```
"a";"b";"c";"d"
"a";"b;c";"c";"d"
"a";"b"c";"c";"d"
```

I save this data as test_SO.txt and read it with read.csv as follows:

```
df <- read.csv("/Users/Al/Documents/test_SO.txt", header=F, quote = "", sep = ";", allowEscapes=T)

     V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
1   "a"    "b"     "c"    "d"    
2   "a"    "b       c"    "c"   "d"
3   "a"   "b"c"    "c"    "d"

df <- read.csv("/Users/Al/Documents/test_SO.txt", header=F, quote = "\"", sep = ";", allowEscapes=T)
```

I would like to read this data as follows:

```
    V1     V2      V3     V4    
1   a      b       c      d  
2   a      b c     c      d
3   a      b c     c      d
```

The problem is that when I escape quotes I cannot escape tabs and vice-versa.

I have tried the solution "readLines, replace delimiter and read", but my data is too large and the function too slow. Is there a way to do that within read.csv itself?

Comment: Looks impossible, since you've got unrestricted quotes and semicolons, so there's no way of telling if a character or sequence of characters is real data or a delimiter. Your example seems like you could use the three characters ";" as a delimiter, but is there anything that guarantees that sequence won't appear within data? I think you're stuck.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, thanks for your reply. Using  ";" as delimiter would do it if read.csv accepted delimiters of more than a byte.

Comment: @AlineMenezes oh you _dont_ want to do something like I did. the `read.*` can be pretty slow, so if those aren't fast enough, you might think about shell or perl or another language

Comment: Hi @rawr, thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm heading to another language, as you say it becomes very slow in R.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a few steps

```
(t1 <- gsub('\";\"', '|', '"a";"b";"c";"d"
"a";"b;c";"c";"d"
"a";"b"c";"c";"d"'))
# [1] "\"a|b|c|d\"\n\"a|b;c|c|d\"\n\"a|b\"c|c|d\""


(t2 <- gsub('\"', '', t1))
# [1] "a|b|c|d\na|b;c|c|d\na|bc|c|d"


(t3 <- gsub('(\\w);?(\\w)', '\\1 \\2', t2))
# [1] "a|b|c|d\na|b c|c|d\na|b c|c|d"


read.table(text = t3, sep = '|')
#   V1  V2 V3 V4
# 1  a   b  c  d
# 2  a b c  c  d
# 3  a b c  c  d
```